# Need Help Getting MySQL Stored Procedure With CASE Statement Working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am attempting to create a stored procedure in MySQL, that I will access with PHP. I am currently getting assistance from an Oracle and MSSQL DBA, but I don't believe some of the information she is providing me is relevant to MySQL.

I have a basic query that returns all the data, but I want to be able to filter if there are any input parameters. If any one of 23 input parameters is present, I want to add to my basic query. The Oracle/MSSQL DBA said I should use a MySQL case statement to achieve this. I had originally just used "null" if the parameters were not present, but she said this was not good practice. So, what I am doing now is if the parameter is present, I want to add to the general query to filter the results. When I attempt to save the stored procedure in MySQL, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE when spVar01 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and alpha' at line 57
```

And here is my stored procedure. Any assistance getting my stored procedure to work will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
use `my_database`;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `queryWithFiltering`;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `queryWithFiltering` (IN var1 INT,IN var2 INT,IN param01 VARCHAR(255),IN param02 VARCHAR(255),IN param03 DATE,IN param04 DATE,IN param05 DATE,IN param06 TINYINT(1),IN param07 INT(11),IN param08 INT(11),IN param09 INT(11),IN param10 INT(11),IN param11 DATE,IN param12 TINYINT(1),IN param13 VARCHAR(50),IN param14 VARCHAR(50),IN param15 DATE,IN param16 INT(11),IN param17 VARCHAR(50),IN param18 DECIMAL(13,2),IN param19 VARCHAR(50),IN param20 VARCHAR(50),IN param21 VARCHAR(50),IN param22 INT(11),IN param23 INT(11))
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'comment goes here ...'
BEGIN
DECLARE spVar01 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE spVar02 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE spVar03 DATE;
DECLARE spVar04 DATE;
DECLARE spVar05 DATE;
DECLARE spVar06 TINYINT(1);
DECLARE spVar07 INT(11);
DECLARE spVar08 INT(11);
DECLARE spVar09 INT(11);
DECLARE spVar10 INT(11);
DECLARE spVar11 DATE;
DECLARE spVar12 TINYINT(1);
DECLARE spVar13 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE spVar14 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE spVar15 DATE;
DECLARE spVar16 INT(11);
DECLARE spVar17 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE spVar18 DECIMAL(13,2);
DECLARE spVar19 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE spVar20 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE spVar21 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE spVar22 INT(11);
DECLARE spVar23 INT(11);

SET spVar01 = param01;
SET spVar02 = param02;
SET spVar03 = param03;
SET spVar04 = param04;
SET spVar05 = param05;
SET spVar06 = param06;
SET spVar07 = param07;
SET spVar08 = param08;
SET spVar09 = param09;
SET spVar10 = param10;
SET spVar11 = param11;
SET spVar12 = param12;
SET spVar13 = param13;
SET spVar14 = param14;
SET spVar15 = param15;
SET spVar16 = param16;
SET spVar17 = param17;
SET spVar18 = param18;
SET spVar19 = param19;
SET spVar20 = param20;
SET spVar21 = param21;
SET spVar22 = param22;
SET spVar23 = param23;

select ... where ...

CASE when spVar01 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and alpha like '%spVar01%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar02 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and beta like '%spVar02%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar03 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and gamma like '%spVar03%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar04 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and delta like  '%spVar04%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar05 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and epsilon like  '%spVar05%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar06 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and zeta like  %spVar06%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar07 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and eta like %spVar07%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar08 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and theta like %spVar08%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar09 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and iota like %spVar09%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar10 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and kappa like %spVar10%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar11 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and lambda like '%spVar11%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar12 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and mu like %spVar12%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar13 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and nu like '%spVar13%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar14 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and xi like '%spVar14%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar15 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and omicron like '%spVar15%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar16 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and pi like %spVar16%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar17 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and rho like '%spVar17%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar18 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and sigma like %spVar18%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar19 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and tau like '%spVar19%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar20 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and upsilon like '%spVar20%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar21 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and phi like '%spVar21%'
END CASE;

CASE when spVar22 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and chi like %spVar22%
END CASE;

CASE when spVar23 IS NOT NULL THEN
    and psi like %spVar22%
END CASE;

order by ID limit var1 offset var2;
END//
```

Comment: Your case statements are pointless... you have no `then` clauses AT ALL. all you've got basically `if(); if(); if(); if();`

Comment: case works like this: CASE WHEN <CONDITION> THEN <VALUE> END, OR CASE WHEN <CONDITION> THEN <VALUE> ELSE <VALUE> END

Also you'll need to look at how to use CASE in where clauses in mysql

Comment: I knew I would forget something when I transcribed the SP. I have added the "THEN"s back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Case statement should look something like this..

```
CASE when spVarXX IS NOT NULL and alpha like '%spVarXX%'
    THEN <DO SOMETHING> 
END CASE;
```

You are also missing quotes in several case statements.   For example:

```
%spVar22%
```

should be

```
'%spVar22%'
```

I would suggest cleaning/reviewing your syntax first and trying again.  Post any errors you have after that and take it step by step.

Comment: Again, the Oracle/MSSQL DBA said I would not need the quotes if the data was an INT. I have also put my "THEN"s back in. Also, the "and zeta like  %spVar06%" is what I am adding to the original query. I want it to read "select ... when ... and zeta like  %spVar06%".

Comment: You are correct about the quotes and the variable types.  The placement of your "thens", however are incorrect.  I would try limiting this to one CASE statement and play with it. It should be something like this:

CASE when spVar01 IS NOT NULL THEN 'alpha' END;

Comment: I got rid of all but one CASE, but still received the same error. Am I appending to my query correctly? Do I need to enclose "and zeta like %spVar06%" in any type of delineator in order for it to be added to my original query?

Comment: Did you revise the CASE statement with proper syntax?  Post your revised SQL.

Comment: I did not. I think you are thinking that I want "and omicron like '%spVar15%'" to be part of the decision making logic, when what I want is to append "and omicron like '%spVar15%'" to then end of the original query if spVar15 is not null. So in the end, the query will be: "select ... where ... and omicron like '%spVar15%'".

Comment: In that case you are going to have to set a variable for each case and append it to the where clause.  See this post where the user was trying to do something similar.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176404/how-to-pass-a-string-as-a-where-clause-in-mysql